# Maintain Parent-Child handle in new Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar, parent-child

Using Android.Studio;

To bring you up to speed, I'm designing a calendar that works like a date picker, a swipe to a list view of events on the date. The events are obtained from our site, and stored in a local database. The CalendarFragment setOnDateChangeListener updates the ScheduleFragment event list. CalendarFragment, ScheduleFragment are children of SectionsPagerAdapter, which is child to HandiCRM. HandiCRM has a variable DBHandler database; which maintains access to the local database, including DROP, CREATE, INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT commands between the necessary Tables. Because these activities all exist at the same time, I've been able to pass public Parent handles to each child to allow something like "Parent.Parent.database"

[tl;dr] Each event setOnClickListener creates a new Intent for ShowEvent.class, which should populate information stored in the database. The problem I seem to be receiving, is that DBHandler returns zero results when trying to select any information from the tables when DBHandler is created inside of ShowEvent. Also, because it's creating an Intent to display this Activity, I can't pass the Parent object, as the Activity is not serializable (and neither is the database). There's a possibility that I can put a crap ton of EXTRAS to display the information required for this page, but it won't allow any modifications there-in. So, what I need, is either a different way to pop up an Activity window to allow me to keep the Object-Oriented Parent->Child handles, or a way to pass a handle to the child outside of EXTRAS.

I've been researching for a while, and even though there have been requests of the same nature, the replies are always the same "use putExtra()" rather than solving the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood your application, I think the best way to deal with your problem is to **make your DBHandler static.**

```
static DBHandler database;
```

Now, in any of the child activities, you should be able to access this variable as:

```
HandiCRM.database
```

> Defining a variable as static allows you to access the variable from
>   any activity within the package.

So, you can then execute queries in the child activity itself. So there would be no need to pass values.

Comment: Future revisions shows that maintaining a variable in another view can cause it to be lost in a garbage collect. This has been turned into a function that returns a new iteration of database if it doesn't exist. Further issues revolved around the fact that if multi-threaded operations access the same variable for multiple read/write sessions, it may conflict with an illegal state. Function was redesigned to always return a new iteration of database.